# railsが上手くインストールされません。初心者ですがどなたか教えてください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Windows のコマンドプロンプトで Railsが上手くインストールされません。解決策を教えてください。

OSはwindows10homeで、Rubyのバージョンは、"ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x64-mingw32]"で、gemのバージョンは、"3.0.3"です。
RubyInstallerでは、Ruby+Devkit 2.6.3-1 (x64) からダウンロードしました。

実際にインストールした流れは、
RubyInstallerからrubyをインストール→MSYS2で"1","2","3"キー入力
です。

そこから、コマンドプロンプトで"gem install rails"を入力すると、

```sh
Done installing documentation for concurrent-ruby, i18n, thread_safe, tzinfo, activesupport, rack, rack-test, crass, mini_portile2, nokogiri, loofah, rails-html-sanitizer, rails-dom-testing, builder, erubi, actionview, actionpack, activemodel, arel, activerecord, globalid, activejob, mini_mime, mail, actionmailer, nio4r, websocket-extensions, websocket-driver, actioncable, mimemagic, marcel, activestorage, thor, method_source, railties, sprockets, sprockets-rails, rails after 377 seconds
38 gems installed
```

最後の行がこのような文だったのでうまくいったと思ったのですが、その後"rails -v"コマンドを入力すると、

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
        28: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
        27: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        26: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
        25: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        24: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        23: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/cli.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        22: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        21: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        20: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        19: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        18: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        17: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        14: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/base.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/line_editor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/line_editor/readline.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/readline.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/readline.rb:10:in `<module:Readline>'
         3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/rbreadline.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/rbreadline.rb:1097:in `<module:RbReadline>': HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory (RuntimeError)
```

このようにエラーが出てしまいます。

しかし `set` コマンドを使って環境変数を調べると、`HOMEDRIVE` と `HOMEPATH` は共に存在しています。

どなたか解決策を教えてください。

追加で、MSYS2で"2"キーを入力すると、最初の文が以下のようになります。

```sh
   1 - MSYS2 base installation
   2 - MSYS2 system update (optional)
   3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain

Which components shall be installed? If unsure press ENTER [] 3

> sh -lc true
mkdir: ディレクトリ `/c/Users/foo' を作成できません: Permission denied
/c/Users/foo could not be created.
Setting HOME to /tmp.
MSYS2 seems to be properly installed
Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain ...
```

Comment: この記事 [RubyInstaller2でWindows環境にRuby 2.4 + Rails 5.0.2をインストールする](https://qiita.com/jnchito/items/08b5be458134073c60e3) だと MSYS2 を先にインストールしているようですが。

Comment: 環境によっては`RubyInstaller2`上でMSYSのインストーラーが動かないときがあるようですので、手動でMSYSをインストールしてみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Comment: もう一度すべてアンインストールしてから上記の通りやり直したのですが、同じようなエラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: 環境変数`HOME`の値はどうなっていますか？`HOMEDRIVE`、`HOMEPATH`と合わせてこれらはディレクトリ(フォルダ)を指すようにとエラーが出ているように見えます。

Comment: 環境変数[HOME]の値は[C:\Users\foo]です。

Comment: もしかしたらこれ [混ぜるな危険 (msys2とCygwinとGit For Windowsを一緒に使ってはいけません)](https://opcdiary.net/%E6%B7%B7%E3%81%9C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AA%E5%8D%B1%E9%99%BA-msys2%E3%81%A8cygwin%E3%81%A8git-for-windows%E3%82%92%E4%B8%80%E7%B7%92%E3%81%AB%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%91%E3%81%BE/) が影響しているかも。「Git For Windowsのツール類はMsys2のランタイム上で動いていますが、このGit For Windowsに付属しているMysy2ランタイムはGit For Windows用のMsys2ランタイムなので、本家のMsys2のランタイムとはソースレベルで異なります。つまりこれらの環境にはそれぞれ互換性が無いので同居させない方が良いし、ましてや全部の環境に対してPATHを通すようなことは絶対にしてはいけません。動かなくなります。」

Comment: Git For Windowsはインストールしていないんですけど、影響ありますか？